# Core-Plus Mathematics: Similar Resources for grades 7-9

Tags: textbooks, teacher-preparation, teaching, common-core, teacher-development

I'm looking for rich educational resources similar to core-plus mathematics, for grades 7, 8, and 9. Is there any such material?

Comment: Are the resources you want for grades 7, 8 and 9 also or for a different level?  Can you tell us more about core-plus math and/or supply a link?

Comment: @AmyB For grades 7-9. About Core-Plus Mathematics: http://www.cpmponline.org/

Comment: Can you point us to a few pages that show the materials, and explain what would make something similar?

Comment: If you click through to "Program Overview" there is a bit more on the Core Plus.  Seems like it emphasizes integrating geometry and algebra and trig.  Also, that it includes some prob/stat.

Comment: Maybe this is radical, but take a look at Saxon as they have a similar approach in mixing the subjects.  Also, they do a lot of rolling review.  The Core-Plus is only grades 9-12, but Saxon has math for junior high (pre algebra).

Comment: @Behzad Editing the link and the other information into the question would improve it.

Comment: Core-Plus is supposedly a high school course, so it starts from 9th grade. What have you found attractive in this program? It dates back to late 1980s, when NCTM released the Curriculum and Evaluation Standards for School Mathematics, and several math programs were developed using NSF grants. Core-Plus was panned by critics and laid dormant for a decade, [until Common Core resurrected it](https://medium.com/@ReflectiveObserver/how-common-core-resurrected-core-plus-mathematics-b51e9ba50348?source=friends_link&sk=b2a3052b6dad3b41984f76851ce1efe4). Publishers don't like to throw away old stuff.